# Alternative to toLocaleString() for chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

```
 function tolocal(str)
 {
 var date, split, dSplit, tSplit, d, raw;
date = '';
split = str.split(' ');
if (split.length === 2) {
    dSplit = split[0].split('-');
    tSplit = split[1].split(':');
}
raw = d.toLocaleString().split(' GMT')[0];

 return raw.substring(raw.indexOf(", ")+2, raw.lastIndexOf(':')) + " " + raw.substring(raw.length-2,raw.length)
 }
```

The above code, works well in ie browser where I get the output in the following format.

**November 13,2012 10:15 AM**

But I am not able to achieve the same in the chrome browser. Is there any other function which will help me achieve the same output?  `date.toUTCString()` provides the same result but I am not sure how different it is to `toLocaleString()` in terms of functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're completely different. What do you need, `martes, 15 de octubre de 2013 12:53:46` or `Tue, 15 Oct 2013 10:53:46 GMT`?

Comment: I need it in October 15,2013 10:53 AM as the final output. I can make few string manipulations to achieve this. But toLocaleString() in chrome gives me 15/10/2013 10:53:00 AM

Comment: So you don't need locale features at all (neither language nor time zone): you want to convert to UTC and display in English with custom format. Sorry, I was confused by the *alternative to toLocaleString()* part.

Comment: So you're looking for it to be represented as UTC time in the custom format given? `Month DD, YYYY HH:MM AM`

Comment: I want it in `Month DD, YYYY HH:MM AM` format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it manually:

```
// Where "date" is a Date object
function dateFormatUTC(date) {
  var months = [
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
  ];

  var hours = date.getUTCHours();
  if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;

  var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
  if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;

  var monthName = months[date.getUTCMonth()];
  var timeOfDay = hours < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';

  return monthName + ' ' + date.getUTCDate() + ', ' +
         date.getUTCFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + timeOfDay;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can use a thirdparty library to do stuff like that: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a good one.
Example:

```
moment(d).format('MMMM Do, YYYY h:mms a');
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using third party library?

Comment: sure, maybe @user2857484 provided usable answer?

Comment: This is going to be your easiest and best option.  Any string input/output directly from the `Date` class will be highly implementation specific.

Answer (score 1):

you can try  using options like below:

```
  var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
          // request a weekday along with a long date
   var options = {weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric"};
     // an application may want to use UTC and make that visible
    options.timeZone = "UTC";
    options.timeZoneName = "short";
    alert(date.toLocaleString("en-US", options));
```

Please find the reference @

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Note, this relies on browser support for part of the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://norbertlindenberg.com/2012/12/ecmascript-internationalization-api/#DateTimeFormat), which you will only find in the very newest browsers.